# Nested TabView - Remove inner tab bar iOS 13, Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I am using a `TabView` to represent three tabs. In iOS 14, this is handled nicely, but iOS 13 results in a gray bottom bar which is the tab bar for navigation. How can I remove this bar?

Please bear in mind that this is a `TabView` within a `TabView`. The outer `TabView`'s bar is shown at the bottom with five tabs; the inner `TabView` bar I do not want shown at all.

The code below represents the inner `TabView`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DashboardView: View {
    @State private var pageIndex = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DashboardTopBar(index: $pageIndex) // A custom selected tab indicator
            if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                TabView(selection: $pageIndex) {
                    RehabView().tag(0)
                    PerformanceView().tag(1)
                    RecoveryView().tag(2)
                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
                .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
            } else {
                TabView(selection: $pageIndex) {
                    RehabView().tag(0)
                    PerformanceView().tag(1)
                    RecoveryView().tag(2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The image below shows iOS 13 on the left and iOS 14 on the right.

[image: Left: iOS 13, Right: iOS 14]

**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**

If the code below is launched on iOS 13, you will note a tab bar on the bottom and an empty tab bar on top of it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var outerTabViewSelectedTab = 0
    @State private var innerTabViewSelectedTab = 1
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $outerTabViewSelectedTab,
                content:  {
                    Text("Outer 1").tabItem { Text("Outer 1") }.tag(1)
                    TabView(selection: $innerTabViewSelectedTab,
                            content:  {
                                Text("Inner 1").tag(1)
                                Text("Inner 2").tag(2)
                            }).tabItem { Text("Outer 2") }.tag(2)
                })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .no))

Comment: @Dc7 Unfortunately, `.indexViewStyle` and `PageIndexViewStyle` are only available in iOS 14. I am looking specifically for iOS 13.

Comment: I think then, you have to create it with UIViewRepresentable!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62305094/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi It doesn't, sorry. I attempted both `true` & `false` values for the translucency but the bar still remains. The other tabs contain list views and the bar overlaps the items.

Comment: I could not reproduce this, so it is probably something in those your custom subviews, either in DashboardTopBar or internals of TabView.

Comment: @Asperi I have added MCV example code to reproduce, as well as my hack solution as an answer. If you can improve it I'd accept your answer.

Comment: Why are you adding that `TapView` if you don't want it to be visible?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini So that in iOS 14 the swipe functionality of TabView is usable.

Comment: So if it is only for iOS 14, why don't you get rid of it on iOS 13?

Comment: If the solution is simple using a TabView and a single property modifier then there is little benefit in creating more work than necessary by designing a custom tab view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hide it explicitly... as it is for backward compatibility it is safe, because behavior is already known and won't change.

So here is a solution

```
var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $outerTabViewSelectedTab,
            content:  {
                Text("Outer 1").tabItem { Text("Outer 1") }.tag(1)
                TabView(selection: $innerTabViewSelectedTab,
                        content:  {
                            Text("Inner 1").tag(1)
                             .background(TabBarAccessor { tabBar in
                                tabBar.isHidden = true
                             })
                            Text("Inner 2").tag(2)
                        }).tabItem { Text("Outer 2") }.tag(2)
            })
}
```

Used `TabBarAccessor` from my other solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59972635/12299030

Comment: Great! And of course, for those wondering, the `.background` modifier would need to be applied to all tabs that wish to hide the tab bar. Thanks.