# SwiftUI A blank tabbar height area on the top of tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to insert a new tab which is a SwiftUI view by `UIHostingController` into `UITabBarController`, Like this image:

[image]

The view is very simple,

**ContentView.swift**

```
struct ContentView: View {
       var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Color(.red).opacity(0.2).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                NavigationView {
                    Text("Hello")
                }
            }
}
```

And in **AppDelegate.swift** (disabled Scene) I get the `viewControllers` and insert like this:

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
let view = ContentView()
let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
controller.viewControllers?.insert(viewController, at: 0)
let item = controller.tabBar.items![0]
item.title = "Tab"
window.rootViewController = controller
self.window = window
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

The result is like above image, which is OK. But when I put the `Text` into `NavigationView` like:

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.red).opacity(0.2).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            NavigationView {
                Text("Hello")
            }
        }
}
```

Then the result is:

[image]

There's a gray blank bar which look equal to the tabbar there, how to remove it?

I have tried hide the tab bar by:

```
tabBarController.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

yes, it's gone, but I don't want to hide the tabBar. Any help, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64122705/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi Just tried it's hidden the tabBar same as `tabBarController.tabBar.isHidden = true`.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the translucency of your TabBar to true.

**In Storyboard:**

Set the checkmark *TabBar -> Style -> Translucent*

**Or in code**

```swift
tabBar.isTranslucent = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved by deleting the `UITabBarController` in storyboard and re-added it. The old one was added by older Xcode version. I compared both `UITabBarController`s, didn't see the difference in the interface builder.